# How to test/validate mandatory fields in Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Am new to selenium, Wanna know how to test/Validate the mandatory fields using selenium webdriver.

Ex:
In a page,
Fields like first name, lastname, Email ID, Phone number(Digit only), Submit & Cancel button.

Comment: What have u tried till now??? We will help but we need to know whether you even tried to help yourself or not...

Comment: Please describe what you've tried as of now.

Comment: @Test Engg this is very generic question 
Have you started already or not. Do read Selenium / Webdriver. There are tons of Videos/ blog/ documentation. 
[Official selenium] (http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/index.jsp)
[YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6jc7UurmD4&list=PLi3B1HriJRbk3MBhn19ByZZXaXHQ81FVe)
Start yourself 1st & if U have  any question, post it it here.

Comment: thnx for ur replies. . am done just positive scenarios only

Comment: 'Assert.assertEquals("Value is required and can't be empty", driver.findElement(By.id("country")).getText());     I used this comment for each field but i want user to give the input and if user left any field blank alert message should display using Selenium webdriver

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Conductor](http://conductor.ddavison.io) framework this is very simple:

```
public void testValidation() {
  click("input[type='submit']")
  .validateTextPresent("Fields are required")
  .setText("input[type='first_name']", "first name")
  .click("input[type='submit']")
  .validateTextPresent("Fields are required") // still can't continue
  // ... (do that for every field)
}
```

of course substitute the css selectors with the relevant fields on your web page.  this is just pseudo-code